# How to speed up cell increment in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell

I need to apply integer increment on a cell in a Pandas DataFrame. The code below works correctly. However, it is very slow in a loop:

```
df.at[index, column_name] += 2
```

Is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a lot simpler:

```
df[columns] += 2
```

Or, if you want to do it for every column:

```
df += 2
```

If you have a special selection of indexes to use, try this:

```
indexes = [0, 4, 5, 8]
columns = ['a', 'b', 'k']
df.loc[indexes, columns] += 2
```